# How to set daily toast in app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I wrote a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINPRT) App**. One of the features of  this app is **alarm/reminder**.

For Example: user sets the **Reminder** at **7AM** in **app's Reminder Page**. App must give alarm/reminder **daily** at **7AM**. Now as I got to know, that alarm and reminder are not available in Windows Phone 8.1, so I thought of using **Toast**.

How will this app give a toast at user set time **everyday**.? 
Also, how to make this app run in **background** for this purpose.

Any other **better solution** for this problem?

Comment: [What search terms did you use?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202965(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I read that  alarm and reminder are not available in Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is running a background process, it will be invoked every 30 minutes or so. You won't be able to get it to send out a toast notification exactly at 7am as far as I know, but you can get it within 15 minutes or so of 7am.

You can also schedule a toast notification to occur. Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868224.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I want to do it with the combination of: background task, timer, MaintainanceTrigger, ScheduledToastNotification. Can you help me?

Comment: From what I've read, MaintenanceTrigger only works if the phone is plugged in. BackgroundTask fires every 30 mintues or so, so it might not be accurate enough for your purposes. ToastNotification is your best bet - (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868224.aspx.)

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into this?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I think this might answer your question